# C#,can Extension methods be added to user defined classes in C#(not base classes)

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I have a user defined class

```
public class Student
{
    int rollno;
    public getrollno()
    {
        return rollno;
    }
}
```

I want to have extension method `checkifRollnoIs1()` which will return true or false.

Can I do it & how can I do it?

Comment: why do you want it to be an extension method?

Comment: Agree with Matt - why use extension method, when you can just modify the class? The whole point of the extension methods is the ability to "extend" classes, when there no other way to ad functionality.

Answer (score 6):

Here is one way to write one:

```
public static class StudentExtensions
{
  public static bool checkifRollnoIs1(this Student s)
  {
    return s.getrollno() == 1;
  }
}
```

By the way - extension methods are not actually added to a class, they just appear that way (intellisense magic).

Comment: You're missing the variable name: `public static bool checkifRollnoIs1(this Student student) { return student.rollno == 1; }`

Comment: @VVS - Yeah, noticed that several minutes ago.

Comment: Assuming rollno is public. For private variables this would need reflection.

Comment: @VVS - which is why I used the public method instead when re-reading the OP code.

Comment: @VVS - perhaps you should refresh the page before you add further comments ;)

Comment: On a side note, I would suggest to add a test for `null` (`ReferenceEquals(s, null)` to be on the safe side) since the method could be called directly with `StudentExtensions.checkifRollNoIs1(foo)`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can add an extension method.

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static bool checkifRollnoIs1(this Student student)
    {
        return student.getrollno() == 1;
    }
}
```

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)

Though if you have access to the source, why do you need an extension method?

Answer (score 1):

You can add extension method for "any" object that could be passed to a Static method for some operation.

For compiler, extension method  is nothing more than a static method.

If you have a extension method for "CheckIfRollNoIs1", in that case your call,

```
studentObj.CheckIfRollNoIs1()
```

gets converted to,

```
StudentExtensions.CheckIfRollNoIs1(studentObj)
```